# Reshape DataFrame column into multiple columns, and other columns into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame and I need to turn one column into multiple columns, and then create another column that index/labels values of the new/multiple columns

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'state':['AK','AK','AK','AK','AL','AL','AL','AL'], 'county':['Cnty1','Cnty1','Cnty2','Cnty2','Cnty3','Cnty3','Cnty4','Cnty4'], 
        'year':['2000','2001','2000','2001','2000','2001','2000','2001'], 'count1':[5,7,4,8,9,1,0,1], 'count2':[8,1,4,6,7,3,8,5]})
```

[image]

Using `pivot_table()` and `reset_index()` I'm able to move the values of year into columns, but not able to dis-aggregate it by the other columns.

Using:
pivotDF = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['state', 'county'], columns = 'year')
pivotDF = pivotDF.reset_index()

Gets me close, but not what I need.

What I need is, another column that labels count1 and count2, with the values in the year columns. Something that looks like this:

[image]

I realize a DataFrame would have all the values for 'state' and 'county' filled in, which is fine, but I'm outputting this to Excel and need it to look just like this so if there's a way to have this format that would be a bonus.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `pivot` then `stack`

```
s=df.pivot_table(index=['state','county'],columns='year',values=['count1','count2'],aggfunc='mean').stack(level=0)
s
Out[142]: 
year                 2000  2001
state county                   
AK    Cnty1  count1     5     7
             count2     8     1
      Cnty2  count1     4     8
             count2     4     6
AL    Cnty3  count1     9     1
             count2     7     3
      Cnty4  count1     0     1
             count2     8     5
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got most of the answer down. Just add a stack with `level=0` to stack on that level rather than the default year level.

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['state', 'county'], columns='year', values=['count1', 'count2']) \
    .stack(level=0)
```